# Ad-Hoc Validation is not executed

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a simple entity called `Game`. I want to allow my users to edit multiple of these entities at once. Therefore I need a form that contains multiple `Game` Entities.

The problem: When the form is submitted and I invoke `hasErrors()` my custom ad-hoc `validate` method in the `Game` entities is never called. Only the validations marked by annotations are checked and produce errors when they are invalid.

This is the `Game` Entity:

```
@Entity 
public class Game extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Constraints.Required
    public Team team1;

    @ManyToOne
    @Constraints.Required
    public Team team2;

    //the validate method does not get called
    public String validate()
    {
        System.out.println("Validating the Game Entity.");
        if(team1.id == team2.id)
            return "You have to choose two different teams!";

        return null;
    }    

    public static Model.Finder<Long,Game> find = new Model.Finder<Long,Game>(Long.class, Game.class);
}
```

This is the Form that contains multiple `Game` Entities.

```
public class GameForm {

    @Valid
    public List<Game> games;

    public GameForm()
    {
        games = new ArrayList<Game>();
    }   
}
```

This is the controller method.

```
public static Result save()
{
    Form<GameForm> gameForm = form(GameForm.class).bindFromRequest();

    if(gameForm.hasErrors())
        return badRequest(create.render(gameForm));

    return redirect(
        routes.Games.index()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that ad-hoc validation only works on the "top" object.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms

For your Form this is probably List, not Game.