# Applying @Required Constraints for jpa entity with @ManyToOne annotation PLAY FRAMEWORK

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.2

I have problems with applying validation constraints to class properties
for example I have class:

```
        @Entity
        public class user   {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            public int id;

            @Required
            public String name;

            @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
            @Required
            public Company company;
        }
```

When I apply @Required to parametr: name it works.
But when I add adnotation @ManyToOne for parametr: company it dosnt work no more. 
When I remove @ManyToOne adnotation it works back again.
Please help me.

company class:

```
@Entity 
public class Company {
  @Id
  @Constraints.Required
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  public Long id;

  @Constraints.Required
  public String name;

  @Constraints.Required
  public String date;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `@ManyToOne` you can get DB validation so that the company field is non nullable. If you use

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="company", nullable=false, optional=false)
public Company company;
```

And `@Required` checks for Client Side validation. So you can create a method to handle validation. Which is equivalent.

```
public String validate() {
   if(company == null) {
       return "Company Field Cannot be Empty";
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: So if I use '@ManyToOne' relation I have to made custom ad-hoc validation? I've added '@Required' adnotation to parametr id of class company. And now in the fom I can see constraint: required. Now I need to make it red when input is null. Ad-hoc validation should be in model of that class?

Comment: Found similar problem:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741421/ad-hoc-validation-is-not-executed